# How can you register RDS instance with OpsWorks stack using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks, amazon-rds

I am trying to register an existing RDS instance with opswork stack using cloudformation. But unable to find any example or reference inside AWS documentation.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation doesn't support register RDS instance with opsworks stack.

But it's still possible, you can use CloudFormation custom resource to register RDS instance into a stack: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

Comment: Could you please explain more or provide an example? I am having the same issue. Thank you